# How to handle variables used in mysql to convert the query into Redshift

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

I have a query to convert from MySQL compatible to Amazon Redshift compatible:

```sql
FROM abc
                    INNER JOIN def ON abc.ledger_id = def.ledger_id
                    INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT @a: = 0
                        ) AS a
                    INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT @b: = 0
                        ) AS b
                    INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT @c: = ''
                        ) AS C
```

How to handle this in Amazon Redshift?

```
FROM abc
                    INNER JOIN def ON abc.ledger_id = def.ledger_id
                    CROSS JOIN (
                        SELECT  0
                        AS a)
                    INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT 0
                        AS b)
                    INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT null
                        AS C)
```

Comment: Amazon Redshift does not support variables. It is based on PostgreSQL syntax

Comment: `cross join (select 0 as a, 0 as b, null as c)`?